# Parallel vs Serial results aren't understandable

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

There is something weird in the test results below.
I did parallel and serial loop and compared them with each other.
I did the test as one of 4 shapes *parallel* , *serial* , *parallel loop first then serial loop* , and lastly *serial loop first then parallel loop*. I coded them as p , s, pfsl, and sfpl respectfully.

the results are as in table

| type of test and # | time taken in milli second |
| --- | --- |
| until = 4 |  |
| p#1 | 9,472 |
| s#1 | 13,459 |
| s#2 | 11,323 |
| p#2 | 8,854 |
| p#3 | 9,253 |
| s#3 | 10,669 |
| until =5 |  |
| pfsl#1 | 1,421 |
|  | 8,299 |
| sfpl#1 | 1,708 |
|  | 6,280 |
| sfpl#1 | 1,657 |
|  | 6,334 |
| pfsl#2 | 1,400 |
|  | 8,191 |
| pfsl#3 | 1,443 |
|  | 8,488 |
| sfpl#3 | 1,784 |
|  | 6,475 |

could someone explain this? and how always the second method lasts longer?

you can do the same test in [here](https://github.com/2a34-cmd/Programming-ANN/tree/6d98aa0c66c3045f2e4ddfaef894d0f2e756b3a4)(just export the project as it is, and run the main method )

minimal reproducible code:

The serial method

```cs
for(int i = somenum; i >= until; i-- ){

    foreach (var nue in nuelist)
    {
        foreach (var path in nue.pathlist)
        {
            foreach (var conn in nue.connlist)
            {
                Func(conn,path); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The parallel method

```cs
for(int i = somenum; i >= until; i-- ){

    Parallel.ForEach(nuelist,nue =>
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(nue.pathlist,path=>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(nue.connlist, conn=>
            {
                Func(conn,path);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Inside Path class

```cs
Nue firstnue;
string name;
List<Conn> Conns;
public void Func(Conn conn,Path path)
{
    List<Conn> list = new(){conn};
    list.AddRange(path.list);
    _ = new Path(list); 
}
public Path(List<Conn> conns)
{
   //other things
   Conns = new();
   Conns = conns;
   Paths.TryAdd(name,this);
   firstnue.pathlist.Add(this);
   /*
   firstnue is another nue that will be 
   in the next iteration of for loop
   */
}
public static ConcurrentDictionary<string,Path> Paths = new();
```

Inside Nue class

```cs
public ConcurrentBag<Path> pathlist;
public Nue()
{
    pathlist = new ConcurrentBag<Path>();
}
```

Inside Conn class

```cs
Nue From;
Nue To;
public Conn(Nue From, Nue To)
{
    this.From = From;
    this.To = To;
}
```

in main method

```
using System.diagnostics;
StopWatch watch = new();
watch.start();
// for serial results, uncomment lines that are below
// serial(somenum = n,until = l);
// watch.stop();
// int s = watch.elapsed;

// for parallel results, uncomment lines that are below
// parallel(somenum = n,until = l);
// watch.stop();
// int p = watch.elapsed;

// for sfpl results, uncomment lines that are below
// serial(n,l);
// watch.stop();
// int sf = watch.elapsed;
// watch.restart();
// parallel(n,l);
// int pl = watch.elapsed;

// for pfsl results, uncomment lines that are below
// parallel(n,l);
// watch.stop();
// int pf = watch.elapsed;
// watch.restart();
// serial(n,l);
// int sl = watch.elapsed;
```

Comment: Your code does not compile. And the defiition of `Nue` is missing.

Comment: You're missing one part of [Minimal, reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): *Completeness*. Tip: Try creating a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net) showing the issue.

Comment: If there's someone who knows something like "the second method is always taking more time, despite swapping the places of invoking calls", especially if the problem is about parallel vs serial,  it could be more helpful than trying to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Believe me, we *are* trying to help. In case you didn't get the hint, us asking for a reproducible problem, and the lack of helpful comments in 2 days should indicate that this is an *extremely unusual* phenomenon.  If anything, it's usually the first runs that are slower - which is why every decent benchmark will perform warmup runs before measuring.

Comment: Your question is not well structured. You are showing 18 measurements, and then you are asking *"how always the second method lasts longer?"*, before having shown to us the first and the second method. Then you are posting some code fragments that belong to different code files, and a link to a GitHub repository that contains the whole project, which we are supposed to download and run. Questions here are supposed to be self-contained. Everything needed should be included in the question. Please create a minimal example, that can be included in the question in its entirety.

Comment: No it's not. The code can't run at all. There's no data, no code that prints or even measures the results so people can guess what `spffl` even means. Reproducible means that *other people* can take your code and run it. That's impossible here. If you try to run `Parallel.ForEach` with a 2-item array the partitioning overhead alone will cause it to run slower than a simple loop. Besides, your code doesn't seem to be doing anything other than add items to fields that are never used

Comment: To get proper benchmark results use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/getting-started.html) and create one method for each case you want to test. BDN will run your code until the results become stable and a statistically valid result can be calculated. This accounts for warmup, cooldown and transient effects. Post the BDN results *and* code that others can execute to reproduce those results

Comment: I added an answer that shows how a benchmark should be written and measured. In large matrix multiplication `Parallel.For` results in 9x improvement on a 6-core hyperthreaded machine.

Answer (score 1):

My results on large matrix multiplication are very different. On a 6-core machine, a correct `Parallel.For` can result in 9 times better performance. That's 6 times for the cores and another 3 due to hyperthreading:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.22621
Intel Core i7-10850H CPU 2.70GHz, 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.302
  [Host]     : .NET 6.0.7 (6.0.722.32202), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET 6.0.7 (6.0.722.32202), X64 RyuJIT


           Method |      Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Ratio |
----------------- |----------:|---------:|---------:|------:|
       SerialMult | 288.63 ms | 5.736 ms | 8.585 ms |  1.00 |
     ParallelMult |  75.92 ms | 1.311 ms | 1.162 ms |  0.26 |
 ParallelMultTemp |  49.63 ms | 0.873 ms | 0.817 ms |  0.17 |
 ParallelMultVect |  33.04 ms | 0.588 ms | 0.521 ms |  0.11 |
```

The question's code is incomplete and very hard to read. It doesn't seem to be doing anything other than adding items to lists too. It's impossible to say what the result numbers mean or why they are this way.

The linked project mentions neural networks though, so a meaningful real benchmark would be matrix multiplications. In an MLP, the feed-forward stage is all about matrix multiplications.

`Stopwatch` isn't useful for benchmarking as execution can be delayed by other programs. Even executing the same method lots of times and averaging the results isn't enough, as there may be spikes, warmup and caching effects. That's why almost every benchmark these days uses the [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html) package. BDN will run a benchmark as long as it has to until it gathers enough measurements to provide a statistically correct result.

The multiplication code [was borrowed from this article](https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/matrix-multiplication-in-parallel-with-c-and-the-tpl/).

The serial multiplication method is :

```
static double[,] MatrixProduct(double[,] matrixA,
    double[,] matrixB)
{
    int aRows = matrixA.GetLength(0); int aCols = matrixA.GetLength(1);
    int bRows = matrixB.GetLength(0); int bCols = matrixB.GetLength(1);
    if (aCols != bRows)
        throw new Exception("xxx");

    double[,] result = new double[aRows, bCols];

    for (int i = 0; i < aRows; ++i) // each row of A
    for (int j = 0; j < bCols; ++j) // each col of B
    for (int k = 0; k < aCols; ++k) // could use k < bRows
        result[i,j] += matrixA[i,k] * matrixB[k,j];
    return result;
}
```

A naive parallel version simply replaces the outer loop with `Parallel.For`

```
static double[,] MatrixProductP(double[,] matrixA,
    double[,] matrixB)
{
    int aRows = matrixA.GetLength(0); int aCols = matrixA.GetLength(1);
    int bRows = matrixB.GetLength(0); int bCols = matrixB.GetLength(1);
    if (aCols != bRows)
        throw new Exception("xxx");

    double[,] result = new double[aRows, bCols];

    Parallel.For(0, aRows, i =>
    {
        // each row of A
        for (int j = 0; j < bCols; ++j) // each col of B
        for (int k = 0; k < aCols; ++k) // could use k < bRows
            result[i, j] += matrixA[i, k] * matrixB[k, j];
    });
    return result;
}
```

A slight tweak is to use a temporary variable for the inner loop instead of writing directly to the result array:

```
static double[,] MatrixProductPTemp(double[,] matrixA,
    double[,] matrixB)
{
    int aRows = matrixA.GetLength(0); int aCols = matrixA.GetLength(1);
    int bRows = matrixB.GetLength(0); int bCols = matrixB.GetLength(1);
    if (aCols != bRows)
        throw new Exception("xxx");

    double[,] result = new double[aRows, bCols];

    Parallel.For(0, aRows, i =>
    {
        // each row of A
        for (int j = 0; j < bCols; ++j) // each col of B
        {
            double temp=0;
            for (int k = 0; k < aCols; ++k) // could use k < bRows
                temp += matrixA[i, k] * matrixB[k, j];
            result[i, j] = temp;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Going even further, the row from `matrixA` is copied into a local vector at the start of each parallel loop, to reduce even further the chance of cache misses and non-local access:

```
static double[,] MatrixProductPVect(double[,] matrixA,
    double[,] matrixB)
{
    int aRows = matrixA.GetLength(0); int aCols = matrixA.GetLength(1);
    int bRows = matrixB.GetLength(0); int bCols = matrixB.GetLength(1);
    if (aCols != bRows)
        throw new Exception("xxx");

    double[,] result = new double[aRows, bCols];

    Parallel.For(0, aRows, i =>
    {
        double[] row = new double[aCols];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(matrixA, i*aCols*sizeof(double), row, 0, aCols*sizeof(double));

        for (int j = 0; j < bCols; ++j) // each col of B
        {
            double temp=0;
            
            for (int k = 0; k < aCols; ++k) // could use k < bRows
                temp += row[k] * matrixB[k, j];
            result[i, j] = temp;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

To benchmark matrix multiplication the following .NET 6 code is used. This is the whole Program.cs file

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information

using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run(typeof(Program).Assembly);

[MarkdownExporterAttribute.StackOverflow]
public class SerialVsParallel
{
    private const int L = 500;
    private const int N = 1000;
    private const int M = 200;

    private double[,] _matrixA;
    private double[,] _matrixB;
    
    public SerialVsParallel()
    {
        
        _matrixA = new double[L,M];
        _matrixB = new double[M,N];

        var random = new Random(42);
        for (var i = 0; i < L; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < M; j++)
            {
                _matrixA[i, j] = random.NextDouble();
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                _matrixB[i, j] = random.NextDouble();
            }
        }
    }

    static double[,] MatrixProduct(double[,] matrixA,
        double[,] matrixB)
    {
        int aRows = matrixA.GetLength(0); int aCols = matrixA.GetLength(1);
        int bRows = matrixB.GetLength(0); int bCols = matrixB.GetLength(1);
        if (aCols != bRows)
            throw new Exception("xxx");

        double[,] result = new double[aRows, bCols];

        for (int i = 0; i < aRows; ++i) // each row of A
        for (int j = 0; j < bCols; ++j) // each col of B
        for (int k = 0; k < aCols; ++k) // could use k < bRows
            result[i,j] += matrixA[i,k] * matrixB[k,j];
        return result;
    }
    
    static double[,] MatrixProductP(double[,] matrixA,
        double[,] matrixB)
    {
        int aRows = matrixA.GetLength(0); int aCols = matrixA.GetLength(1);
        int bRows = matrixB.GetLength(0); int bCols = matrixB.GetLength(1);
        if (aCols != bRows)
            throw new Exception("xxx");

        double[,] result = new double[aRows, bCols];

        Parallel.For(0, aRows, i =>
        {
            // each row of A
            for (int j = 0; j < bCols; ++j) // each col of B
            for (int k = 0; k < aCols; ++k) // could use k < bRows
                result[i, j] += matrixA[i, k] * matrixB[k, j];
        });
        return result;
    }

    static double[,] MatrixProductPTemp(double[,] matrixA,
        double[,] matrixB)
    {
        int aRows = matrixA.GetLength(0); int aCols = matrixA.GetLength(1);
        int bRows = matrixB.GetLength(0); int bCols = matrixB.GetLength(1);
        if (aCols != bRows)
            throw new Exception("xxx");

        double[,] result = new double[aRows, bCols];

        Parallel.For(0, aRows, i =>
        {
            // each row of A
            for (int j = 0; j < bCols; ++j) // each col of B
            {
                double temp=0;
                for (int k = 0; k < aCols; ++k) // could use k < bRows
                    temp += matrixA[i, k] * matrixB[k, j];
                result[i, j] = temp;
            }
        });
        return result;
    } 
    
    static double[,] MatrixProductPVect(double[,] matrixA,
        double[,] matrixB)
    {
        int aRows = matrixA.GetLength(0); int aCols = matrixA.GetLength(1);
        int bRows = matrixB.GetLength(0); int bCols = matrixB.GetLength(1);
        if (aCols != bRows)
            throw new Exception("xxx");

        double[,] result = new double[aRows, bCols];

        Parallel.For(0, aRows, i =>
        {
            double[] row = new double[aCols];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(matrixA, i*aCols*sizeof(double), row, 0, aCols*sizeof(double));
            // each row of A
            for (int j = 0; j < bCols; ++j) // each col of B
            {
                double temp=0;
                
                for (int k = 0; k < aCols; ++k) // could use k < bRows
                    temp += row[k] * matrixB[k, j];
                result[i, j] = temp;
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
    

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public double[,] SerialMult() => MatrixProduct(_matrixA,_matrixB);

    [Benchmark]
    public double[,] ParallelMult() => MatrixProductP(_matrixA,_matrixB);
    
    [Benchmark]
    public double[,] ParallelMultTemp() => MatrixProductPTemp(_matrixA,_matrixB);

    [Benchmark]
    public double[,] ParallelMultVect() => MatrixProductPVect(_matrixA,_matrixB);
    
}
```

Running this produces the following output

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.22621
Intel Core i7-10850H CPU 2.70GHz, 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.302
  [Host]     : .NET 6.0.7 (6.0.722.32202), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET 6.0.7 (6.0.722.32202), X64 RyuJIT


           Method |      Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Ratio |
----------------- |----------:|---------:|---------:|------:|
       SerialMult | 288.63 ms | 5.736 ms | 8.585 ms |  1.00 |
     ParallelMult |  75.92 ms | 1.311 ms | 1.162 ms |  0.26 |
 ParallelMultTemp |  49.63 ms | 0.873 ms | 0.817 ms |  0.17 |
 ParallelMultVect |  33.04 ms | 0.588 ms | 0.521 ms |  0.11 |
```

On a 6-core machine, the naive parallel method is 4 times faster than the serial method. That's certainly *not* as fast as it should be. Simply using the `temp` variable though resulted in 6x faster execution than the serial method. Copying the row into a local buffer results in 9 times better performance than the serial version

That's because reading and writing across rows in the inner loop results in a lot of cache misses. Using the `temp` variable eliminated some of these. Using a copy of the row reduces cache misses even further *and* allows the processors to take advantage of hyperthreading