# How do I parallelize this matrix by vector multiplication?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I need to parallelize this code. As you can see, the `q` array contains values that are summed at every loop.

```
/// <summary>
/// q = A * d, with A stored in CSR format.
/// </summary>
public static double[] Multiplication(int order, double[] d, List<double> A, List<int> J, int[] I)
{ 
    double[] q = new double[order];

    for (int i = 0; i < order; i++)
    {                    
       int indexFirst = I[i];

       q[i] += A[indexFirst] * d[J[indexFirst]];

       for (int j = indexFirst + 1; j < I[i + 1]; j++)
       {
          int col = J[j];
          double a = A[j];

          q[i] += a * d[col];

          q[col] += a * d[i];
       }
   }

   return q;
}
```

I was able to parallelize the code in this way (splitting the problem in a CPU count number of sections and summing up resulting `q` arrays in the end) but it seems overcomplicated. Any better idea?

```
Parallel.For(0, cpuCount, delegate(int i)
{
    MultiplySection(startIndices[i], endIndices[i], d, A, J, I, qSection[i]);
});

double[] q = new double[order];

for (int j = 0; j < cpuCount; j++)
{
    for (int i = startIndices[j]; i < order; i++)
    {
        q[i] += qSection[j][i];
    }
}

private static void MultiplySection(int startIndex, int endIndex, double[] d, List<double> A, List<int> J, int[] I, double[] q)
{
    for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
    {
        int indexFirst = I[i];

        q[i] += A[indexFirst]*d[J[indexFirst]];

        for (int j = indexFirst + 1; j < I[i + 1]; j++)
        {
            int col = J[j];
            double a = A[j];

            q[i] += a*d[col];

            q[col] += a*d[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe using SIMD would be a great application for this: [Use SIMD-accelerated numeric types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/simd) It would be much faster than feeding it to multi threading, which probably gives more overhead than this.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen SIMD can speed things up 2 times (the code uses doubles), only with specially written code. Proper use of parallelization can speed up things by *more* than the number of cores, if hyperthreading is used.

Comment: There's no need to specify the CPU count, `Parallel.For` will use it by default to calculate data partitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation is coarse grained, so if a CPU core is busy with something else you risk having poor utilization at the end of your process.

I would at least try using the built in partitioning by Parallel.For. This should give a much fine grained concurrency that might help with efficiency. You can also use localInit/localFinally methods to create and merge your arrays:

```
public static double[] Multiplication(int order, double[] d, List<double> A, List<int> J, int[] I)
{
    double[] qTotal = new double[order];

    Parallel.For(0,
        order,
        () => new double[order], // LocalInit
        (i, loopState, q) => // Main Body
        {
            int indexFirst = I[i];

            q[i] += A[indexFirst] * d[J[indexFirst]];

            for (int j = indexFirst + 1; j < I[i + 1]; j++)
            {
                int col = J[j];
                double a = A[j];

                q[i] += a * d[col];

                q[col] += a * d[i];
            }
            return q;
        },
        q => // Local Finally 
        {
            lock (qTotal)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < q.Length; i++)
                {
                    qTotal[i] += q[i];
                }
            }
        });
    return qTotal;
}
```

If the amount of work inside the loop body is small you might still benefit from batching, but you might want to use a fixed batch size instead of basing it of the number of processors. This should help a bit with various types of overheads. You will likely need to experiment a bit to find your optimal batch size.

Comment: This is the professional touch I was looking for my parallel code! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you help me with this *Local Finally* implementation too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76392102/can-i-use-kahan-summation-in-the-parallel-for-local-finally-section

Answer (score 1):

The following code, from an answer to [Parallel vs Serial results aren't understandable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72678263/parallel-vs-serial-results-arent-understandable/73042954#73042954) results in 9x faster performance in a 6-core hyper-threaded machine. That's 1.5 the number of cores. It could be improved perhaps with SIMD operations for another 2x-4x speedup, depending on the CPU's SSE/AVX register size

```
static double[,] MatrixProductPVect(double[,] matrixA,
    double[,] matrixB)
{
    int aRows = matrixA.GetLength(0); int aCols = matrixA.GetLength(1);
    int bRows = matrixB.GetLength(0); int bCols = matrixB.GetLength(1);
    if (aCols != bRows)
        throw new Exception("xxx");

    double[,] result = new double[aRows, bCols];

    Parallel.For(0, aRows, i =>
    {
        double[] row = new double[aCols];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(matrixA, i*aCols*sizeof(double), row, 0, aCols*sizeof(double));
        // each row of A
        for (int j = 0; j < bCols; ++j) // each col of B
        {
            double temp=0;
            
            for (int k = 0; k < aCols; ++k) // could use k < bRows
                temp += row[k] * matrixB[k, j];
            result[i, j] = temp;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

The main performance killers in parallel processing is synchronization and non-local memory access.

- It's faster to access values that are already in the CPU's cache than going to RAM.
- It's also faster to have each core work with is own partition of the
  data than trying to synchronize access to the same data.
- With the cached data, it's faster to access values along a row instead of
  jumping N items to get to the next column on the next row.
- Finally, when calculating totals it's faster to calculate a *local* total,
  that's stored in a CPU register, than trying to increment a shared
  variable.

This code takes advantage of these rules in the following way:

- `Parallel.For` will partition the rows among all the cores, with each core accessing its own consecutive rows
- Processing works along rows, which means the data are close together and usually already in cache
- `System.Buffer.BlockCopy` makes a local copy of each row so the cores don't have to synchronize access to RAM.
- The `temp` total is calculated locally, inside the column loop.

The multiplication code [was borrowed from this article](https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/matrix-multiplication-in-parallel-with-c-and-the-tpl/).

The answer uses BenchmarkDotNet to compare multiple multiplication versions, from sequential, to naive parallel, to using local row copies

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.13.1, OS=Windows 10.0.22621
Intel Core i7-10850H CPU 2.70GHz, 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
.NET SDK=6.0.302
  [Host]     : .NET 6.0.7 (6.0.722.32202), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET 6.0.7 (6.0.722.32202), X64 RyuJIT


           Method |      Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Ratio |
----------------- |----------:|---------:|---------:|------:|
       SerialMult | 288.63 ms | 5.736 ms | 8.585 ms |  1.00 |
     ParallelMult |  75.92 ms | 1.311 ms | 1.162 ms |  0.26 |
 ParallelMultTemp |  49.63 ms | 0.873 ms | 0.817 ms |  0.17 |
 ParallelMultVect |  33.04 ms | 0.588 ms | 0.521 ms |  0.11 |
```