# Can I use Kahan Summation in the Parallel.For Local Finally section?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

After implementing [this matrix by vector multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76380355/261010) with a `Parallel.For` loop, I need to sum the results with [Kahan Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) to reduce the numerical errors. Is it possible?

This is my *Local Finally* implementation:

```
double[] qTotal = new double[order];
double[] c = new double[order];

Parallel.For(0,
    order,
    () => new double[order], // LocalInit
    (i, loopState, q) => // Main Body
    {
       int indexFirst = I[i];

       q[i] += A[indexFirst] * d[J[indexFirst]];

       for (int j = indexFirst + 1; j < I[i + 1]; j++)
       {
           int col = J[j];
           double a = A[j];

           q[i] += a * d[col];

           q[col] += a * d[i];
                    }
           return q;
        },
        q => // Local Finally 
        {
           lock (qTotal)
           {
              // Kahan Sum
              for (int i = 0; i < q.Length; i++)
              {
                  double y = q[i] - c[i];     // So far, so good: c is zero.

                  double t = qTotal[i] + y;   // Alas, sum is big, y small, so low-order digits of y are lost.
                  c[i] = (t - qTotal[i]) - y; // (t - sum) recovers the high-order part of y; subtracting y recovers -(low part of y)
                  qTotal[i] = t;              // Algebraically, c should always be zero. Beware overly-aggressive optimizing compilers!
                                              // Next time around, the lost low part will be added to y in a fresh attempt.
              }
           }
        }
     });
```

It does not seem to work as expected, results are slightly different from the non-parallel version. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Will it be a thread deadlock problem? You can use TimedLock instead of Lock.
TimedLock throws an exception even if the lock cannot be acquired in time, and it also warns you if you have some unreleased locks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't think you will have many thread collisions in your accumulation ( you are doing matrix multiplication so you probably won't) you can try using Interlock instead of lock.  Interlock is faster and it will save you some memory.  Since you will be modifying 2 numbers you will need a gate.  Interlock does not support boolean, so you will have to use integers.

Write a function like this:

```
private static void ThreadSafeKahanSum(ref double Value, ref double C, ref int gate, double addend)
{
    while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref gate, 1, 0) != 0) 
    { 
        //You should not get inside of here very often.
        //You can keep a collision tally for research if you like:
        //Interlocked.Increment(ref kahanSumCollisionCount);
        //If you are getting a lot of collisions, then maybe find another way.
        //Or just leave it blank.
    }
    double y = addend - C;
    double t = Value + y;
    C = (t - Value) - y;
    Value = t;
    gate = 0;
}
```

Now rewrite you code into something like this:

```
double[] qTotal = new double[order];
double[] c = new double[order];
int[] gates = new int[order];
Parallel.For(0, order,
    (i, loopState) => // Main Body
    {
        int indexFirst = I[i];
        ThreadSafeKahanSum(ref qTotal[i], ref c[i], ref gates[i], A[indexFirst] * d[J[indexFirst]]);

        for (int j = indexFirst + 1; j < I[i + 1]; j++)
        {
            int col = J[j];
            double a = A[j];

            ThreadSafeKahanSum(ref qTotal[i], ref c[i], ref gates[i], a * d[col]);
            ThreadSafeKahanSum(ref qTotal[col], ref c[col], ref gates[col], a * d[i]);
        }   
    });
```

This way you are taking full advantage of Kahan sum in a thread safe way.

If someone has a better way please let me know.  I have faced the same problem with Kahan sum for many years and this is the best thread safe method of Kahan sum I have come up with.